# Can we show that non-determinism adds no power, for some specific running time?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, polynomial-time, nondeterminism

$NP = \cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} NTIME(n^k)$

$P = \cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} TIME(n^k)$

Can we show that $NTIME(n^k) = TIME(n^k)$ for a specific $k$?

For how large of a $k$ can we show the above statement to be true?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? (Come on people, how did this get six upvotes? It's a problem dump like any other.)

Comment: Well, $k=0$ seems like an easy place to start...

Comment: @Raphael I just learned about this today. This is not part of a homework problem (if that's what you mean by "problem dump"). I barely have the mathematical background at this point to solve this - I was just curious.

Comment: See this prior answer, which is essentially a duplicate of the current Question, ( http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1079 ) for $k=1$.

Comment: Our policy generally doesn't depend on whether it was assigned to you as a homework.  "Problem dump" means that the question provides only the statement of a problem, without showing anything about what you've tried or where you got stuck and without formulating a specific question about some aspect of the problem.  Such questions are often discouraged, for reasons explained [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question).  It's often better to make a serious attempt before asking, and show us what approaches you tried.

Comment: @D.W. I see. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $\mathsf{NTIME}(n^k) \subseteq \mathsf{TIME}(n^\ell)$ for any $k,\ell$ then $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$. Indeed, any problem $L \in \mathsf{NP}$ can be solved in non-deterministic time $O(n^r)$ for some $r$. Consider now the problem $L' = \{0^{|x|^{r/k}}1x : x \in L\}$. Clearly this problem is still in $\mathsf{NP}$, and furthermore the previous algorithm solves it in non-deterministic time $O(n^k)$. Therefore $L'$ has a deterministic algorithm running in time $O(n^\ell)$, implying that $L$ has a deterministic algorithm running in time $O(n^{r(\ell/k)})$.

This trick is known as *padding*.